# Visual Basic Sound On Left Click

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to make a sound clicker in visual basic how would I play a sound when I click my left mouse button. I have tried multiple things none have worked, I'm new to coding so if stuff does not look good please don't come at me ty!.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Declare Sub apimouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dx As Int32, ByVal dy As Int32, ByVal cButtons As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Int32)
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
    Dim toggle As Integer

    Private Sub MetroTrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles MetroTrackBar1.Scroll
        Label2.Text = MetroTrackBar1.Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub MetroTrackBar2_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles MetroTrackBar2.Scroll
        Label1.Text = MetroTrackBar1.Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Randomize()
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Dim minval As Integer
        Dim maxval As Integer

        minval = 1000 / MetroTrackBar1.Value
        maxval = 1000 / MetroTrackBar2.Value

        Timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(maxval, minval)
        If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then
            apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MetroButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click
        toggle = toggle + 1
        If toggle = 1 Then
            Timer1.Start()
            MetroButton1.Text = "Toggle Off"
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
            toggle = 0
            MetroButton1.Text = "Toggle On"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Seems like a fairly complicated code sample here for what going by your description is just playing a sound in the mouse click event on the form.  Maybe you need to expand on your question a little and give us some more context

Comment: @Hursey How would I add a sound to the "mouse click event"

Comment: Handle the form.MouseClick() event is the basics. but like I said, seems to be a whole heap more going on here than just simply playing a sound.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Are you trying to play this sound only when you click within your app or when you click anywhere while your app is running? It's a very important distinction.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm trying to make a auto clicker that plays sound on the left click.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. A left click when ANY application is focused, or only just YOUR application?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up one event sub for the Form. This will play the sound for any blank area of the form.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseClick, TextBox1.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Windows\Media\notify.wav")
    End If
End Sub
```

To have the sound play when you click in a control, assign this event to the MouseClick event of each control in the Designer property window. Just click the lighting bolt and a list of events will appear. Form1_MouseClick will appear in the drop down list next to the event. Just select it.

[image]